# Why does python.logger error out or time out when script runs for a long period of time?

Tags: python, logging

I'm running a python script that usually runs anywhere between 6-30 hours. I use the python logger module to log messages to a text file. Sometimes the script randomly fails with the error message: "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'info'" on the following code statement:

```
if args.isNational == 1:
    log.info("Started computing xyz...")
```

Why does this happen? And what is the best way to mitigate this?

Comment: At some point during execution, you are assigning something else to the name `log`.

Comment: If its always happening in the same place, look for `log = whatever` in that chain of execution. You could wrap that `log.info()` call in a try/except and `print(log.info)` which should print something like `<function the_offending_function at ...>` giving you a better idea what ended up in there.

Comment: I'm certainly not assigning something else to the same log. And it does not always happen at the same place. I'll try the try/except but at this point it seems like the log handler just dies or something if the script takes a long time to execute. Is that even possible?

Comment: I figured out the issue - the original log handler was running in a different spark context. I started a new spark context and tried to access the original log handler and it didn't seem to work. The error went awat when I continued in the same spark context.